Stats on successful leave open
From looking at some FAQ, it seems like 5 close votes are needed within the aging window to close a question unless enough (again seems like 3) number of leave open votes are cast (to remove it from the review queue and leaving it with the possibility of a direct close).
My question: Can anyone share any statistics on what proportion (%) of the questions that enter into close-review queue manage to get bumped off the review queue at least once because of enough number of leave open votes(i.e. I am not asking about questions re-entering the close queue or getting closed via enough direct close votes)?
If there are no such accurate statistics, any empirical data or educated guesses?

It seems like this query gives this data wanted as the outcomes match up with actual post’s timeline. Editing gives totals, but it is unclear if they are for review actions or the result of the review. If it is the last one, there can be an answer.

Very nice. Thanks!! The second link, if accurate suggests near equal record for leave open as close
